# Getting Rid of (Hiding) Android TabWidget's "Focused State"

Tags: java, android, tabwidget

Okay, so here's the idea; I want to create a set of icons that persists on the bottom of the screen across all the activities I have on my app. The first thing that came to my mind was the TabWidget.

After I spent some time with it, I realized that I can't get the "focused state" off the tabs, I know tabs are supposed to work out that way but the idea is to making those tabs looks like icons - it shouldn't looked like they were focused all the time.

I tried using `tabHost.setBackgroundColor(color)` but unfortunately it did not work as I expected.

Here's some visualization to ease off the problem.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF7fu.png

*p.s., sorry about the link. As a new user I weren't allowed to post images directly on the post.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a custom `Selector` for the tab states that is identical regardless of whether or not the tab has focus. This might look something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press" />
</selector>
```

You'd add that to your drawable directory, and then configure your tabwidget to use that in your activity (like so):

```
TabWidget tabWidget = getTabWidget();

for(int i = 0; i < tabWidget.getChildCount(); i++) {
RelativeLayout tabLayout = (RelativeLayout) tabWidget.getChildAt(i);
tabLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_indicator));
}
```

A much more detailed guide is [here](http://ondrejcermak.info/programovani/custom-tabs-in-android-tutorial/comment-page-1/). See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In general you should have a 'focused state' to indicate what is active for those devices without a touch screen (i.e. Google TV) or to assist the accessibility tools for the visually impaired. If you still want to go down the route of hiding the 'focused state' see Femi's answer regarding custom selector.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the selected style like Femi shows is the way to do this..